# how to fix the error local variable 'ListQuery' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, list, filter

i have a function in views.py that list all records and allow user to search for specific record where if filter the class **"suspect"** the problem that i got is once i tried to search the system crash and display the below error :

> local variable 'ListQuery' referenced before assignment Request
>   Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/list/ Django
>   Version:  2.1.3 Exception Type:   UnboundLocalError Exception Value:
>   local variable 'ListQuery' referenced before assignment Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop\ABenvironment\myABenv\blog\views.py
>   in listANDsearch, line 186 Python Executable: C:\Users\LT
>   GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe Python
>   Version:  3.7.1

## Traceback

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/list/
>
> Django Version: 2.1.3 Python Version: 3.7.1 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'blog', 
>   'widget_tweaks',  'import_export'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> > File "C:\Users\LT
> >     GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
> >     in inner
> >       34.             response = get_response(request)
> >
> > File "C:\Users\LT
> >     GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
> >     in _get_response
> >       126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
> >
> > File "C:\Users\LT
> >     GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
> >     in _get_response
> >       124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> >
> > File "C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop\ABenvironment\myABenv\blog\views.py" in
> >     listANDsearch
> >       186.         elif ListQuery == []:
> >
> > Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /blog/list/ Exception Value:
> >     local variable 'ListQuery' referenced before assignment

## views.py

```
def listANDsearch(request):
    #deny anonymouse user to enter the  list page
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        queryset = suspect.objects.all()
        # return render(request,"blog/list.html", {"object_list":queryset})

        #search 
        query=request.GET.get("q")
        print("search for :",query)

        if query == "":
            messages.error(request,"Search field is empty!")
            print("Search field is empty!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

        elif query:

            queryset_list=queryset_list.filter(
              Q(suspect_name__icontains=query)|
              Q(suspect_father_name__icontains=query)|
              Q(suspect_mother_name__icontains=query)|
              Q(content__icontains=query)|
              Q(create_date__icontains=query)
                  # Q(user__first_name__contains=query)
            ).distinct()
            ListQuery = list(queryset_list)
            #paginator in order to make several pages 
            paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10) # Show 5 items per page
            page_request_var = "page"#this line to change dynamicly the string befor the number of page like **page 1** or **abc 1**
            page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
            queryset = paginator.get_page(page)

            context={
                "object_list":queryset,
                "title":"List Items",
                "page_request_var":page_request_var,
            }
            return render(request,"blog/list.html", context)
        elif ListQuery == []:
            messages.error(request,"Record not found/does not exist!")
            print("Record does not exist!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement with 3 separate conditions. You have defined `ListView` in the second one and trying to access it in the third conditional statement. Therefore you are getting this error. You need to update your code such as:

```py
# views.py
def listANDsearch(request):
    try:
        #deny anonymouse user to enter the  list page
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("login")
        else:
            queryset = suspect.objects.all()
            # return render(request,"blog/list.html", {"object_list":queryset})

            #search 
            query=request.GET.get("q")
            print("search for :",query)

            if query == "":
                messages.error(request,"Search field is empty!")
                print("Search field is empty!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                return redirect("login")

            elif query:

                queryset_list=queryset_list.filter(
                  Q(suspect_name__icontains=query)|
                  Q(suspect_father_name__icontains=query)|
                  Q(suspect_mother_name__icontains=query)|
                  Q(content__icontains=query)|
                  Q(create_date__icontains=query)
                      # Q(user__first_name__contains=query)
                ).distinct()
                ListQuery = list(queryset_list)

                # move your conditional statement here
                if ListQuery == []:
                    messages.error(request,"Record not found/does not exist!")
                    print("Record does not exist!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                    return redirect("login")
                else:
                    #paginator in order to make several pages 
                    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10) # Show 5 items per page
                    page_request_var = "page"#this line to change dynamicly the string befor the number of page like **page 1** or **abc 1**
                    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
                    queryset = paginator.get_page(page)

                    context={
                        "object_list":queryset,
                        "title":"List Items",
                        "page_request_var":page_request_var,
                    }
                    return render(request,"blog/list.html", context)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception occurred.")
        return redirect("login")
```

Comment: i tried your answer it display  this error `The view blog.views.listANDsearch didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: Ok you didnt have a redirect url in your if statement, I've added it. I've edited my answer.  Please check.

Comment: There was one ome redirect missing, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Is it possible if an exception is occurred, and you can't catch it? Please see my updated answer.

Comment: also i tried to add the exception but still the same error

Comment: Can you share the error in detail in your question please? And where the exception occurs.